# SQL SERVER How do you insert multiple rows using Insert into select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query, the commented line is what i want to insert

```
insert into tbl_StockTransactions(ItemCode,TransactionDate,Narration,Docid,ReferenceNo,Qty,Price,UserId,BranchCode,StaffCode) select ItemCode,getDate(),Description,PostingDocid,'New Ref',Qty,Price,'uid','bc','sc' from tbl_PostingDetailsStock where PostingReference='A000275'
--select ItemCode,getDate(),Description,PostingDocid,'New Ref',Qty,Price,'uid','bc','sc' from tbl_PostingDetailsStock where PostingReference='A000276';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
insert into tbl_StockTransactions(
    ItemCode, TransactionDate, Narration, Docid, ReferenceNo, Qty,
    Price, UserId, BranchCode, StaffCode
)

SELECT ItemCode, getDate(), Description, PostingDocid, 'New Ref', Qty, 
    Price, 'uid', 'bc', 'sc' 
FROM tbl_PostingDetailsStock 
WHERE PostingReference IN ('A000275','A000276')
```

Comment: Sorry for those who have answered, this what i wanted

Comment: @EmmanuelOgoma, if it meets your requirements, click on check mark below just upvote button [flag it as Accepted] of this Answer.. to help in future use

Answer (score 0):

```
 insert into tbl_StockTransactions(ItemCode,TransactionDate,Narration
 ,Docid,ReferenceNo,Qty,Price,UserId,BranchCode,StaffCode)
 select ItemCode,getDate(),Description,PostingDocid,'New Ref',Qty,Price,'uid','bc','sc' from tbl_PostingDetailsStock
 where PostingReference IN ('A000275','A000276')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ItemCode,getDate(),Description,PostingDocid,'New Ref',Qty,Price,'uid','bc','sc' 
into tbl_StockTransactions
from tbl_PostingDetailsStock 
where PostingReference='A000275'
```